# Prevent deletion of certain column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to prevent deletion of some Columns say A to G Column using VBA.

[image]

Any suggestions, how to achieve this.

I am new to VBA and unable to find any guide related to preventing deletion of some columns.

Comment: Instead of using VBA, just use the inbuilt Excel protection options.

Comment: @BigBen I am creating sheet by fetching external data. Based on data, I want to prevent some column deletion

Comment: You can still use Excel protection in that case most likely.

Comment: @BigBen How Can I do "Excel protection" programatically? could you please share some resource

Comment: Suggest you do it while running the macro recorder. That should get you started.  You can then edit the code to meet your specific requirements. Post back with details and your code if you run into problems.